# Serial upvoting was reversed twice

Tags: discussion, moderators, votes

Though it is legitimate that serial upvoting/downvoting must be reversed. I just want to know on what basis the upvotes are being reversed?

I am asking this because from my account serial upvoting was reversed **twice** in just two days. So, clearly I was happy and then sad and then happy and then sad again. Happy because I was able to access the mod tools for a while. (*I had crossed 2000 rep*)

Being a [high voter](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) on Hinduism.SE and holder of [voxpopuli badge](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi?userid=93), I have also voted many posts in a day. Will this count as serial voting?

I think whoever has upvoted my posts had read them and upvoted me. It is just he/she might have visited my profile and started to look at my each post, which I think is normal.

PS: Neither I have relation with the upvoter nor I bribed them to vote me :)

Comment: He is old user but recently started active on Hinduism site. Dont worry automated script & mods are there to take proper action against such problem.

Comment: @Kedarnath How do we know who voted for us?

Comment: @moonstar2001 only SE developers can see that part, nobody else.

Comment: @Kedarnath Clearly moderator KeshavSrinivasan knows who is casting what vote. He pointedly asked me reasons for downvoting his question/answer in 1 or 2 instances  and in another, asked me to reverse my downvote to his answer after providing a response to my objection. Is he a developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, will answer your question in parts :-

**I just want to know on what basis the upvotes are being reversed?**

Reason is already provided to you by the system, they are reversed because of *Serial Upvoting*

**I have also voted many posts in a day. Will this count as serial voting?**

No, this won't be counted as a serial voting, but if there is anything suspicious, say, you are voting a specific user only then surely they will be reversed manually if not in 24 hours then after certain days (if you escape from system auto reversal).

**I think whoever has upvoted my posts had read them and upvoted me.**

No he didn't and hence system reversed his bulk voting. If you see your profiles *reputation tab*, I'll explain your first reversal here which is **-140**

Over here, system has reversed the votes which were cast by the user in a minute

[image: Serial Voting Reversal for -140]

But if you see, system didn't reversed the +10 reputation which was legit. Now if you say that the user read all your post in a minute is obviously not possible hence, this justifies first reversal.

Coming to the second reversal which was also for **-140**, where the user votes your posts in a minute again

[image: Serial Voting Reversal for -140 for the second time]

So over here, system reversed entire reputation because the user cast the votes in a minute. On the other hand, you do have high upvotes but you up vote good posts regardless of the user and hence your votes are distributed evenly. Also, you do not vote the posts in bulk.

**It is just he/she might have visited my profile and started to look at my each post, which I think is normal.**

It is normal, but voting without reading the posts isn't.

**Neither I have relation with the upvoter nor I bribed them to vote me**

Yes you don't and you didn't.

**So what should I do now?**

Don't worry, I've checked your profile and everything's clean at your end, if this repeats for the third time, the user who is behind this will be banned but you need to flag a moderator to notify this behavior if happens again.

> Note : Serial voting is taken seriously on StackExchange, any foul
>   play with any user will result in suspension, so don't play with your
>   privileges, use them wisely.

Comment: Seriously, no one will flag for moderator attention for serial upvotes. Well, the scenario is completely different if it is serial downvotes :). BTW, I agree with your post.

Comment: @Mr_Green Even if system fails to reverse the serial voting, the votes will be reversed manually + you may get banned, so its better to flag a moderator that somthings wrong with voting and we will keep a check so that you don't get suspended for foul play.

Comment: sure then.. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: This happened again. I just want to know is it the same person who gave me serial up-votes twice before?

Answer (score 2):

[Answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/326/467) explained all your queries. Addition to it.

**What is a Serial Voting ?**

When a single user starts voting against a single user's post in certain time then it is called as Serial Voting. This can be serial upvotes or serial downvotes. There is a automated script running on each SE sites for checking such kind of voting frauds. When this script find such cases then it reverse the action and take note of the user who actually did this action.

In most cases this happens because

- user is not agree with you
- wants to take any revenge
- playing with voting system by using all 40 votes in single day
- is a sock-pa pet.

Voting is encouraged on SE sites but playing with voting system is taken seriously. Normally such user's account gets deleted by moderator after inspection.

You do not need to worry as long as you are not engage with anything in this. Just do your regular work of asking question,answering,editing etc.  And if anything happens by mistake then site moderators & community moderators are there to solve the issue.