# Is Someone Targeting Me?

Tags: discussion

**MOOD : *I'm not angry, this is set of quotes with humble suggestions and informations, don't read it in angry way.***

I don't know why someone would have upvoted my questions, but why would someone just change his mind and start unupvoting and downvoting, *sometimes it seems strategic*.

If someone has problem, there's always a solution, *but there's no expression or reasoning behind*. It hurts not because I'm loosing rep(I will gain nothing with the reps in my life), but I'm not able to understand my faults.

I would like to request members of the community to be responsible.

- Its good upvoting and downvoting QA, but giving reason will always help the user to do better.
- Try not to inject your personal feelings in the QA, its open to all, you liked the question, but you didn't like the person, so you downvoted him, this shouldn't happen, it will degrade the overall rep of community
- I would rather suggest to simply flag the question which you feel offensive/needing mod help, rather downvoting them, question are questions, if you find structural mistakes either edit them or ask the asker to compromise with his writing skills.

**Why I'm concerned ?** I'm attaching a screenshot of my [reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/499/mr-k?tab=reputation), I'm not at all concerned about anyone not liking my questions or answers, but the path the list shows, it seems someone saw my profile, he felt disgraced(I don't know what I wrote on that), and then he started looking at my questions and answers, he found, 'What I upvoted his question?', and then he unupvoted it. ***This resembles Targeting***.

This can be the case of anyone here, I have a strict suggestion to people, please stop bother yourself whose behind question or answering, use your free will but please, if you find question potential enough give them credit, they can be the part of helping someone else(if correctly interpreted). One of our [member](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/serial-upvoting-was-reversed-twice) has also gone through similar instance.

> [image]

**But How can it be Termed as Targeting ?**

- Those posts are old, you need to search them to get to them, they even don't come in first five pages of QA.
- Most are unupvotes, *why would someone just change his/her mind*.
- Because of my liberal views which I suggest above, I usually don't downvote, until I find it very strict to do so, and being strict, I try to reason with the person whom I downvoted, clearly mentioning myself being the downvoter.
- The question on which I'm unupvoted, are very old, meaning, the person who did that belongs to the older generation of the site, more experienced or in equal experience to me. *A not expected thing from a responsible guy*.

**Is this a problem of the Community ?** I'm seeing we are maturing, people are adding up.Due to the growth its becomes more responsible for old guys, to carry forward the Hinduism.SE values to new before deciding, I have suggestion to New as well as Old members.

*To New Members :* We are here to gain knowledge, not to gain rep, don't be disheartened if someone doesn't like your answer or question, world consist of liberal people, everyone has his own thought value and we should respect that. Don't start a war in here. Even a downvote cost less than a upvote, SE is well made and maintained.

*To Old Members :* You will come accross with people with mearge knowledge, but we know, they are here to increase that. We should not show our disrespect towards them. Everyone needs everyone's help. I'm a stupid person and I know that, but I want to wash It away and that could only be done by experienced and knowledgeable hands. It feels bad if an experienced fellow member does such. *Because older people are always responsible to take the community to a direction, its always their will which direction they choose.*

**End Note :**
***Sorry*** if I hurt someone, my intentions are pure, I cannot prove them though. I'm not a perfect human not even close to it, and ***I'm in support of a notion that 'I can be completley wrong about my ideology for the unupvotes?'***, but in case I'm right and if these types of things are happening and kept happening, can result in non responsive members, and will somehow play a part in communities rep loss.

Comment: Seems strange, on SO the votes get locked after 5 or 7 mins. may be this is not applicable to beta sites.

Comment: @Mr_Green, I didn't knew that .... yes might be in beta, its not applicable.

Answer (score 8):

Is Someone Targeting Me? - **NO**

I checked your profile and I see no suspicious activities there so there is no need to panic. You've hardly lost -20 reputation which I think is no big deal. Say if a user is reading your posts and feel that they are not interesting / unique or are low quality they will tend to down vote.

Talking about the unupvote part, SE has kept this feature for a reason. Generally votes gets locked after 5 mins (not sure about the time, I think its 5 or 15 minutes) and later user cannot change their votes on your post unless and until you or someone else edits.

Reason why people can withdraw their votes back is because, say I upvoted one of your post and I upvoted because I liked. Later on you edit your post which I feel is not interesting anymore, or it changes the entire meaning of your question in that case I'll withdraw my vote back or I can change my upvote to a down vote.

**So what you can do here?**

Noting, sit back, relax, read questions and answers, participate as you are participating, engage in activities on the site and keep learning. You cannot comment on a user who un upvoted just 2 posts of yours, see the brighter side, you've got 905 rep in your account.

Also, a moderator cannot do anything here, this is not a foul play, instead this is an opinion thing where user is changing his opinion and withdrawing his votes back. Surely this isn't a good practice if he is not providing a reason to do so which may help you improving your post, but again, can't blame anyone.

Comment: For sure, I'm with you, and strictly, the whole post was not for those -20 reps, believe me, *you need to read my question again*. The posts were dead for a month, no edits nothing, secondly, I even said I may be wrong, but such things can happen, just pointed suggestions. It will never matter me with 905 or 9005 reps, its always a honor being a  part, that I'll always be. And **panic**, my question might suggest that but not my description.

Comment: @Mr.K  I saw your posts as well, they are edited, so it may happen that user voted, later you edited, so that makes the votes unlocked for the users who post unless and until they read your new post. And yes I agree that you are not talking about -20rep, but again, none of the posts are dead on any of the StackExchange sites, when you edit your posts, they show up on active tab, if you don't edit and say new users visit the old questions and answers they tend to upvote and downvote depends upon the users interest. So no doubt this was intentional but we cannot do anything :)

Comment: thanks for the kind response, I know its not in your hand, neither I expected anything, just want to share information, and to inform, new as well as some old ones, what type of things can happen, again, **Apologies**, I can be wrong too.

Comment: @Mr.K I will certainly help users if someone is down voting their posts in bulk or regularly for no good reason but I cannot help when users just retract their votess. So if you think someone is down voting your posts regularly and on purpose, feel free to flag and request for vote patterns check, surely mods will help you.

Comment: thanks, will be helpful in future.